# PHP SQL - How to add product options

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm creating an "e-commerce" website. Right now the code displays all products in a database in their respective categories, I can choose a quantity and add it to the shopping cart.

However, I would like to have an option to choose a color of the product as well, in just a simple list of options, where all available colors will show. Sort of like you're choosing clothing size in e-shops. But I can't seem to figure out how should it work, especially on the PHP side.

Here is the code I'm using to display products:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $box): ?>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="img/<?=$box['img']?>" class="card-img-top" alt="<?=$box['name']?>">
        <div class="card-body">
            <span class="name" style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: 600"><?=$box['name']?></span><br>
            <span class="price" id="bebas" style="font-size: 20px;">
                &dollar;<?=$box['price']?>
                <?php if ($box['rrp'] > 0): ?>
                <span class="rrp">&dollar;<?=$box['rrp']?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </span>
            <br>
            <form action="index.php?page=cart" method="post">
                <input type="number" class="mt-2" id="bebas" style="font-size: 18px;" name="quantity" value="1" min="1"
                    max="<?=$box['quantity']?>" placeholder="Quantity" required>
                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?=$box['id']?>"><br>
                <input type="submit" class="btn mt-3 btn-addtocart btn-sm" value="Add To Cart">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: _"But I can't seem to figure out how should it work"_ - which exact part of this process are you having trouble with? Displaying the options? Generating the options? Storing them?

Comment: You can store product colors in a separate table like `colors` table with a `product_id` column which references a product in the product table. Then `Join` two tables and get the product info using SQL.

Comment: @El_Vanja I don't understand how to display the options on the product card. My understanding is that I will create a table "colors", add an option picker to the product card which will contain all the colors in the table (I think I can just include all colors for all products for now without further specification) and then when I choose a color it will get assigned to the product somehow. But not sure how to display the options.

Comment: Well, you've described it. You have the options stored in the database, you read them and generate a picker in a fitting form element, like a select or a radio button. Have you tried creating this? It's just dynamic HTML output, much like the one you're already creating in the code you've included in the question.

Comment: @El_Vanja Thank you. I got the option select to display the colors in the table. Now I just need to have the selected color display in the shopping cart.

Comment: I'm guessing that `<form action="index.php?page=cart" method="post">` does the adding? If that's the case, your color element needs to be inside the form and then it will submit it alongside the rest of it.